# 3X4 keypad with round buttons as seen in iPhone Phone App responsive for all screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, autolayout, uikit

Can anyone help me break Apple's approach to create the [phone app keypad screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muil3.png)? I have tried creating it with UIStackView with buttons of 1:1 and many other approaches but all in vain. I want to use such a screen in my own project for learning

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muil3.png) is what I want and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azTbP.png) is what I have so far, [Xcode view of storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epGD0.png)

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, and show how the result is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vI7m5RTYNng

Well explained and has code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Part of solution may involve custom (round, green) buttons. To create a button with a red background (as a caution against critical action), I subclassed NSButton:

```
class ColorButton: NSButton
```

And its draw(...) method.

That gave me control over appearance. All other behavior inherited from NSButton.

Additionally, the @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable tags exposed the custom control in InterfaceBuilder.

That was the easy part. Getting the appearance just right was a non-trivial effort (for me) as Cocoa buttons have some subtle behaviors (e.g. disabled, highlight). Responding to desktop color options (such as Dark Mode) is also a consideration.

Here is code for my ColorButton which, again, was to alter the background color not the shape.

```
@IBDesignable
class ColorButton: NSButton {

    @IBInspectable var backgroundColor: NSColor = NSColor.controlBackgroundColor
    { didSet { needsDisplay = true } }

    @IBInspectable var textColor: NSColor = NSColor.controlTextColor

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {   
        //  fill in background with regular or highlight color
        var backgroundColor = (isHighlighted ? self.backgroundColor.highlight(withLevel: 0.75) : isEnabled ? self.backgroundColor : NSColor.gray)!
        if  isEnabled == false      { backgroundColor = NSColor.lightGray }
        let textColor = (isEnabled ? self.textColor : NSColor.disabledControlTextColor )
        var rect: NSRect = NSRect(x: 7.0, y: 5.0, width: self.frame.width - 14.0, height: self.frame.height - 13.0) // self.frame//   dirtyRect
        var path = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, xRadius: 4.0, yRadius: 4.0)
        backgroundColor.setFill()
        NSColor.darkGray.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 0
        path.fill()
        path.stroke()

        let font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: (rect.height) * 0.66)
        let text = title as NSString
        let textFontAttributes = [convertFromNSAttributedStringKey(NSAttributedString.Key.font): font!, convertFromNSAttributedStringKey(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor): textColor] as [String : Any]
        let size = text.size(withAttributes: convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary(textFontAttributes))
        let location = NSPoint(x: ((self.frame.width - size.width) / 2.0), y: ((self.frame.height - size.height) / 2.0) - 3.0)
        text.draw(at: location, withAttributes: convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary(textFontAttributes))
    }// draw
}
```

Above was developed under Swift 3. Swift 4 migration tool added:

```
// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
fileprivate func convertFromNSAttributedStringKey(_ input: NSAttributedString.Key) -> String {
    return input.rawValue
}

// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
fileprivate func convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary(_ input: [String: Any]?) -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? {
    guard let input = input else { return nil }
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map { key, value in (NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: key), value)})
}
```

Comment: I will try that

Comment: NSColor, NSButton, NSFont, NSBezierPath, NSPoint with the UIKit framework?  That's something unheard of.